# Selecting Where ID Must Be In List

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of ids that I'd like to grab off a table. I also have a defined type which looks like the following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "NUMBER_TABLE" as table of number;
```

So basically just an array of number.

What I'd like to do is use that number_table to grab all the rows with a matching primary key off a table. In code, something like

```
select tbl.*
from tbl_myTable tbl
where tbl.id in (select * from table(number_table(12345)))
```

This works but it runs much slower than

```
select tbl.*
from tbl_myTable tbl
where tbl.id in (12345)
```

Looking at the explain plan reports, here's the explain plan for the "tbl.id in (12345)"

[image]

And here's the explan plan for the "tbl.id in (select * from table(number_table(12345)))"
[image]

It seems to be causing gratuitous slow-down in some important areas. Is there anyway to use a list of ids for an index scan like this?

Thanks.

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table, and how much slower was it?

Comment: I tested this with a million row table. I get the exact same execution plans as you, but the performance is excellent and identical in both cases.  I have a feeling that you are not telling us the whole story.  Are you sure you didn't simply look at the plans and simply *assumed* there was a problem?